400 Bad Request Error when requesting Azure Access Token for logged in user
I am setting up SSO for logins to my website from Microsoft login. When the user logs in to Microsoft and redirected back to my website, my site then requests and receives an access token. it works fine. However, if the user is already logged into Microsoft, the request for an access token receives an error, either 400 Bad Request error or sometimes the cURL request times out.
Here is the flow. First, the user click a link to here:
STEP 1:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read&redirect_uri=https://<MY_REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code
STEP 2:
The code comes back to my site in a GET request. This part always works.
https://<MY_REDIRECT_URI>/?code=longcodestring&session_state=sesisonstatestring
When my site receives the code, it uses this PHP cURL request:
STEP 3:
           $curl = curl_init();
           $params = array(
               CURLOPT_URL => 
               "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".AZURE_TENANT_ID."/oauth2/v2.0/token",
               CURLOPT_POST => 1,
               CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>
                   "code=".$_GET['code']
                   ."&grant_type=authorization_code"
                   ."&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/OpenID"
                   ."&client_id=". AZURE_CLIENT_ID
                   ."&client_secret=". AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
                   ."&redirect_uri=". "https://"<MY_REDIRECT_URI>,
               CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
               CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 4,
               CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
               CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
               CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
               CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
               CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                   "cache-control: no-cache",
                   'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   "Content-Length:1025",
               ),
           );

           curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);
           $response = curl_exec($curl);

If the user is actually logging into Microsoft, then the whole process works fine and the $response object returns an access_token. However, if the user is already logged into Microsoft, when clicking the link in STEP 1 the Microsoft login page is bypassed amd it goes immediately to STEP 2 and a code is returned. So STEPS 1 and 2 always work. But STEP 3 fails in this case. The $response is usually "HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed." Sometimes it simply times out the the set timeout limit of 30.
This very specific issue has been raised in the past. Azure AD OAuth Access Token Request ::: 400 - Bad Request
However, this question was 9 years ago and the solution in that case was to add the 'resource' parameter. That parameter is no longer supported, though I believe it was replaced with 'scope' which I am already using.
It makes no sense to me why using the code to get an access token works the first time but not the second since the cURL call always occurs after the user is logged in. So there must be something about the code that is different when not issued from a new login. However there is nothing obviously different in the GET request to my site.

After 2 days of working on this I finally figured it out. Naturally I figured it out not long after I posted the question. :)
The issue had to do with the content-length HTTPHEADER parameter in the cURL request. This request requires that parameter. I set a hard value of 1025 simply because that was in a sample and I haven't had issues with the param in previous cURL requests. The reason for the error was because in some cases it was set too low. I've now set that value to the string length of the POSTFIELDS parameter. Here is the updated cURL request.
                 $post_fields = 
                   "code=".$_GET['code']
                   ."&grant_type=authorization_code"
                   ."&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/OpenID"
                   ."&client_id=". AZURE_CLIENT_ID
                   ."&client_secret=". AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
                   ."&redirect_uri=". "https://"<MY_REDIRECT_URI>;
           $curl = curl_init();
           $params = array(
               CURLOPT_URL => 
               "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".AZURE_TENANT_ID."/oauth2/v2.0/token",
               CURLOPT_POST => 1,
               CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_fields,
               CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
               CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 4,
               CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
               CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
               CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
               CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
               CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                   "cache-control: no-cache",
                   'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   "Content-Length:".strlen($post_fields)
               ),
           );

           curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);
           $response = curl_exec($curl);

I'm now not 100% certain the issue would only arise on the requests for users already logged in. However, that was the only time it was encountered. Maybe the access code is just longer in such cases?
